# Can we implement retry mechanism in a custom receive pipeline of biztalk

Tags: service, biztalk, pipeline

I have a custom receive pipeline in BizTalk 2009 which after receiving the message from a file location connects to a web service to fetch some data. Sometimes there is some issue with the web service and Biztalk is not able to connect to the same and hence the message gets suspended. If we resume the message after say 1-2 minutes the message is processed. So I want to implement a retry mechanism in the receive pipeline only so that there is no manual effort required. can this be done somehow?

Comment: What adapter are you using for the web service call?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to specify the retry semantics on the send adapter which makes the call to the web service.